# Missing dependency in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to build an app for Android but have been getting this error all afternoon:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
   > Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

Just need to run some updates, I would think. So from the app's root I have tried:

```
yarn
```

and then

```
npm i
```

and

```
cup all -y
```

But the problem persists.

**settings.gradle:**

```
rootProject.name = 'MyAppName'

include ':react-native-firestack'
project(':react-native-firestack').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, './node_modules/:react-native-firestack/android/')

include ':react-native-fbsdk'
project(':react-native-fbsdk').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, './node_modules/:react-native-fbsdk/android/')

include ':app'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you run this command (`react-native run-android`) after installing  `react-native-fbsdk`.